# Ansible: how to preserve a variable data type at set_fact

Tags: ansible

The original value that I'm trying to set with Ansible `set_fact` is a string:

```
features/move: "true"
```

Here is a block of code to set the above value:

```
set_fact:
  my_var: "{{ (all_vars | from_yaml).metadata.annotations['features/move'] | default(omit) }}"
```

The value is being set as a boolean `True` as Ansible converts string to boolean by default (source: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11905).

I'd like to print the value preserving its original data type which is a string:

```
{% if my_var is defined %}
my_var: "{{ my_var | lower }}"
{% endif %}
```

Which will give me expected output as a string:

```
my_var: "true"
```

However, what if the original value is a boolean, like:

```
features/move: true
```

With the above logic it will be set as `True`, and then printed out as `"true"` which is not correct.

I have tried expanding my if condition to make it work for both cases above (string and boolean), like:

```
{% if my_var is defined and my_var is string %}
my_var: "{{ my_var | lower }}"
{% elif my_var is defined %}
my_var: {{ my_var | lower }}
{% endif %}
```

However, it always goes into `elif` as the variable data type has been already converted to boolean during the `set_fact` step.

Is there a way to preserve an original data type in Ansible during the `set_fact` step before Ansible converts it to boolean? Any advice is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *... as the variable data type has been already converted to boolean during the `set_fact` step.*

That's correct and the expected behavior.

> *Is there a way to preserve an original data type in Ansible during the `set_fact` step*

Not in general or for all data types. According the documentation about [`set_fact` module – Set host variable(s) and fact(s)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html#notes) it will become a string

> *before Ansible converts it to boolean?*

or

> *Some boolean values (`yes`, `no`, `true`, `false`) will always be converted to boolean type*

However,

> *unless [`DEFAULT_JINJA2_NATIVE`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-jinja2-native) is enabled. This is done so the `var=value` booleans, otherwise it would only be able to create strings, but it also prevents using those values to create YAML strings. Using the setting will restrict k=v to strings, but will allow you to specify string or boolean in YAML.*

**Documentation**

- [Ansible Configuration Settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html)